# Scipy: Convert RGB TIFF to grayscale TIFF and output it on Matplotlib

Tags: python

I want to manipulate **RGB** bands in a TIFF file and output the **grayscale** map on matplotlib. So far I have this code, but I couldn't get it on grayscale:

```
import scipy as N
import gdal
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

tif = gdal.Open('filename.tif')

band1 = tif.GetRasterBand(1)
band2 = tif.GetRasterBand(2)
band3 = tif.GetRasterBand(3)

red = band1.ReadAsArray()
green = band2.ReadAsArray()
blue = band3.ReadAsArray()

gray = (0.299*red + 0.587*green + 0.114*blue)

pyplot.figure()
pyplot.imshow(gray)
pylab.show()
```

And these are the arrays:

```
[[255 255 255 ..., 237 237 251]
 [255 255 255 ..., 237 237 251]
 [255 255 255 ..., 237 237 251]
 ..., 
 [237 237 237 ..., 237 237 251]
 [237 237 237 ..., 237 237 251]
 [242 242 242 ..., 242 242 252]]

[[255 255 255 ..., 239 239 251]
 [255 255 255 ..., 239 239 251]
 [255 255 255 ..., 239 239 251]
 ..., 
 [239 239 239 ..., 239 239 251]
 [239 239 239 ..., 239 239 251]
 [243 243 243 ..., 243 243 252]]

[[255 255 255 ..., 234 234 250]
 [255 255 255 ..., 234 234 250]
 [255 255 255 ..., 234 234 250]
 ..., 
 [234 234 234 ..., 234 234 250]
 [234 234 234 ..., 234 234 250]
 [239 239 239 ..., 239 239 251]]
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: can you expand on what isn't working? what happens if you try to display one band (say red)?

Answer (score 1):

Let's check if the gray is a 2D array (it should be) :

```
import numpy as np
np.shape(gray)
(10, 11) # just an as example
```

then plot it using a gray colormap

```
pyplot.imshow(gray, cmap = pyplot.cm.gist_gray)
```

Take a look of the available color maps at [Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show colormaps](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps).

Cheers.